# KornShell Script: List all even numbers in a range

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, vi

What I am trying to do is list all the numbers that are even, between the two numbers the user enters via a KornShell (ksh) script. So if user enters for the first digit `2` then the second digit `25` it would display

```
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24
```

Answer (score 2):

```
first=2 # from user
last=25 # from user
seq $first 2 $last
```

Comment: plus the default separator of `seq` is `\n`.

Comment: `seq` will be installed, trust me.  :)  But I like @sudo_O's addition of automatically bumping `first` to an even number.

Comment: The question is tagged Unix, not (GNU)/Linux. `seq` is not part of the Unix standard so isn't guaranteed to be installed. Millions of Solaris, AIX and HP-UX machines have no `seq`.

Answer (score 2):

In ksh, assuming you have used variables `start` and `end`:

```
set -A evens                             # use an array to store the numbers
n=0
i=$start
(( i % 2 == 1 )) && (( i+=1 ))    # start at an even number
while (( i <= end )); do
  evens[n]=$i
  (( n+=1 ))
  (( i+=2 ))
done
IFS=,  
echo "${evens[*]}"                       # output comma separated string
```

outputs

```
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24
```

Comment: It works fine with pdksh, ksh93 and dtksh but Solaris 10 ksh (Version M-11/16/88i) does not support the increment operator: `i++ : more tokens expected`. You should use `i+=1` instead. Also, you should separate `n+=1` and `i+=2` in two statements as the colon separator is not supported either by ksh88.

Answer (score 2):

This should work with `ksh93` and `bash`, doesn't require `seq` or `perl` which might not be installed depending on the OS used.

```
function evens {
  for((i=($1+($1%2));i<($2-3);i+=2));do printf "%s," $i;done
  echo $((i+2))
}
```

---

```
$ evens 2 25
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,24
$ evens 3 24
4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,24
$ evens 0 9
0,2,4,8
```

Comment: Using pdksh, I see `ksh: syntax error: '((' unexpected`. Same error on a very old version of ksh on Solaris 8 (Version M-11/16/88i)

Comment: @Glenn jackman Thanks, answer clarified to state a recent release of ksh is expected.

Comment: I think the likelihood of not having `seq` on a system with a modern shell is pretty small, but +1 for an approach that doesn't require extra programs anyway.

Comment: @John Zwinck Not that small, `seq` is not part of POSIX but a GNU specific tool. While it should be on most Gnu/Linux based distributions, it was only included starting with Solaris 11 (so is missing in Solaris 10 and older). `seq` availability is likely similar or worse with AIX and HPUX.

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to do it in shell, `shell script`, `awk`, `seq` etc...

since you tagged question with **`vi`**, I added one with **vim**:

```
fun! GetEven(f,t)
    let ff=a:f%2?a:f+1:a:f
    echom join(range(ff,a:t,2),",")
endf
```

source that function, and type `:call GetEven(2,25)` you will see your expected output.

It currently echoes in command area, if you want it to be shown in file, just use `put` or `setline`, easy too.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -e 'print join q{,}, grep { $_ % 2 == 0 } (shift .. shift)' 2 25
```

It yields:

```
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24
```

---

**EDIT** to fix the trailing newline:

```
perl -e 'print join( q{,}, grep { $_ % 2 == 0 } (shift .. shift) ), "\n"' 2 25
```

Comment: It is missing a trailing newline

Comment: Or, don't explicitly add a newline, but use the `-l` option (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 0):

By setting `first=$(($1+($1%2)))` and using the `-s` option to format the output you can use `seq`:

```
first=$(($1+($1%2)))
last=$2
seq -s, $first 2 $last
```

Save as a script called `evens` and call with even values of `$first`:

```
$ ./evens 2 25
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24
```

Or odd values of `$first`:

```
$ ./evens 3 25
4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24
```

Comment: clever use of integer arithmetic to force an odd starting number to the next even.